# excel: "looping" through columns without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following:

```
A B C ... L N M AL AN AM
1 0 1 ... 0 1 1 0  1  1
0 1 0 ... 1 0 0 0  0  0
```

Is there a formula that loop through each column and compare the value to columns L N M like the above tabe (AL = A AND L, AN = A AND N, AM = A AND M, then BL, BN, BM and so on)?

Edit: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrPlc.png)

Basically in L2, if A2 = 1 and I2 = 1 then L2 = 1 otherwise 0. The same goes for M2 (A2 = 1 and J2 = 2) and N2. Then it repeats for O2 (O2 = B2 and I2) and so on. I was trying to use the offset function and filling the rest of the columns but the problem is I'm not sure how to "loop" back so that each of the column value checks against column I J K like so as seen in the screenshot. I'm at the novice stage of learning Excel and any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Compare and do what? You might be talking about a `COUNTIF` or a `SUMIF` but not clear what your final result should be.

Comment: Your verbiage does not match what you are showing.  Are those the actual columns, or headers in row 1?  You want AL to be `TRUE/FALSE` or `A + L` or `A & L`

Comment: I have edited my post for clarification and included a table. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this **array formula** at `L2` (Enter it then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) and copy/paste it in all cells you want to calculate (see yellow zone in attached picture):

```
=--OR((L$1=$A$1:$H$1&"_"&TRANSPOSE($I$1:$K$1))*($A2:$H2*TRANSPOSE($I2:$K2)))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>   <--------

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the column header contains the concatenation of the two respective columns headers whose values you need my solution is of the form (as a pseudo formula)

`IF(
INDEX(values,MATCH(LEFT(col_head),col_headers) & INDEX(values,MATCH(RIGHT(col_head),col_headers))
="11",1,0)`

In the header I recommend that you use "|" as the divider which can then be used as a marker to determine 'left' from 'right', e.g. `Boy_A|Race_B`.

Doing this the formula in L2 would look like:
`=IF(INDEX($A2:K2,MATCH(LEFT(L$1,FIND("|",L$1)-1),$A1:K1,0))&INDEX($A2:K2,MATCH(RIGHT(L$1,LEN(L$1)-FIND("|",L1)),$A1:K1,0))="11",1,0)`

*Note that the ranges have an absolute reference on the LHS so they always start at column A and a relative reference on the RHS.*